# Match max 5 words before and after a certain word

Tags: regex

I need a regex that will match at most 5 words before and after a certain word.  Example:

the certain word is "the"

the string is "John Ely gets start for the Dodgers, while old friend Takashi Saito gets start for the Brewers in what will essentially be a bullpen game for Milwaukee."

There should be 2 results:

John Ely gets start for **the** Dodgers, while old friend Takashi

Takashi Saito gets start for **the** Brewers in what will essentially

Any ideas???

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "word"? That is a very vague term as it means different things in different languages, and yet something else in regular expressions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,5}the(?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,5}
```

Note however that most regex engines won't deal with overlapping matches.

Comment: so, to make sure that the word the was an actual word, and not part of the word "thesis" or "father" how would one modify the Regex? Basically we just need to make sure that the doesn't have other letters around it, punctuation or spaces are fine though. Thanks!

Comment: @user417669 Add word boundaries, \b, on either side of the search word to force whole-word match only. `(?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,5}\bthe\b(?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,5}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is what seems to work regarding the question asked.
`(?:\s*\w+\s+){0,5}the(?:\s*\w+\s*){0,5}`

Comment: @Jesper I thought about it `(?:\s*\w+\W?\s*){0,5}the(?:\s*\w+\W?\s*){0,5}`, but maybe the comma (,) marks the end of a proposition and the author of the question only wants to keep the words inside the proposition. Apart from that, yes, one can see it as you say. 
Thank you.

Comment: Please add more details to this answer so that it can be understood by the asker.

Comment: @dsillman2000 Are you referring to the original answer or to the comment?