# This Regex is not working only in Solr

Tags: regex, solr, solrnet

[This Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5237978/2463026) is working perfectly in plain C# console application. Based on this we have started using [SolrNet](https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet). Trying to query a Solr instance for a field by using the same regex, throwing exceptions as shown below

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected ']' at position 70 at org.apache.lucene.util.automaton.RegExp.parseCharClassExp(RegExp.java:1087)
```

Comment: Refering to another post is ok, but please include all elements needed for an answer, particularly an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How are you using the regex when querying Solr? Does the query work if you run it directly with Solr without SolrNet?

Comment: The error message tells you the regex engine is Lucene. That means, you might want to use `([-a-zA-Z']+[^-a-zA-Z']+){0,5}the([^-a-zA-Z']+[-a-zA-Z']+){0,5}([-a-zA-Z']+[^-a-zA-Z']+){0,5}the([^-a-zA-Z']+[-a-zA-Z']+){0,5}` - I moved the hyphen to the start of character classes and removed non-capturing `?:` from all groups. Does it work now?

Comment: Please let know if that worked for you once you are online. Lucene regexes are somewhat specific and differ from regular regexps, both POSIX and Perl-like ones.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Thank you for the response. I have tried the given regular expression, but resulted in the below exception..

`
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected '}' at position 60 at org.apache.lucene.util.automaton.RegExp.parseRepeatExp(RegExp.java:1067) 
`

Comment: @user2463026 You have copied the text from the comment above - DO NOT do it as SO inserts rubbish chars into the comment code for it to look nicer. Copy/paste from https://regex101.com/r/C65YB1/1 and please let know if my suggestion works.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : There is no exception this time. and also no data returned. Will update if i can tweak the regex based on your suggestion and got required results from query.

Comment: What results? Please post the text and expected results. Right now, all you ask about is how to get rid of the error and it seems I came up with the right suggestion.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Yes, the suggested answer is working without throwing exception. But at this moment, the whole data is in a solr instance, which i can't share, the regex query which was used, has to return the data what we are expecting, that part we will take care of. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, just one more hint: Lucene regexps also seem to match the whole string (as if they were implicitly anchored with `^` and `$`), so they usually require a whole string match. If that's the problem, add `.*` at the start and end if you need to match a string that "contains" the pattern.

Comment: And one more: in a Lucene regex, a `.` does not match a newline. There is no way to define a DOTALL modifier, you will have to use `(.|\n)` hideous alternation.

Comment: could you explain what are your requirements? lucene has phrase queries that most times are sufficient to build a performant search.

Comment: @Jokin: Given a specific text, need to find the patterns with n words before and after with specific text, in a pool of large words nearly billions in count. For Example, Given text is `stackoverflow.com`, need to return `website stackoverflow.com is` kind of matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Lucene regex engine that is different from the .NET regex engine.

A hyphen is a range operator when it is unescaped *even at the end* of the character class in a Lucene pattern. So, either escape the hyphen or move to the character class start, i.e. `[a-zA-Z'-]` => `[-a-zA-Z']` and `[^a-zA-Z'-]` => `[^-a-zA-Z']`.

It does not look like Lucene regex supports non-capturing groups, so remove all `?:` from the pattern.

So, it will look like

```
([-a-zA-Z']+[^-a-zA-Z']+){0,5}the([^-a-zA-Z']+[-a-zA-Z']+){0,5}([-a-zA-Z']+[^-a-zA-Z']+){0,5}the([^-a-zA-Z']+[-a-zA-Z']+){0,5}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, your use case seems best suited to use a phrase query, did you try it?

a query like "website stackoverflow.com is"~5 could work and would be more performant. If the order it's important, you could use two queries ("website stackoverflow"~5 AND "stackoverflow.com is"~5) and use a custom scorer to remove the ones that are not in order. It will be much more performant.